# java.io.filenotfoundexception on trying to write on an existing file from different file

Tags: java, android

I created a file in internal memory in an activity and want to write on it again on next activity but am getting this error.
in first activity:

```
String id_file = "tt_id";
String key_file = "tt_key";
FileOutputStream outputStream1;
FileOutputStream outputStream2;
try {
   outputStream1 = openFileOutput(id_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   outputStream2 = openFileOutput(key_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   outputStream1.write(id.getBytes());
   outputStream2.write(key.getBytes());
   outputStream1.close();
   outputStream2.close();
```

but in second activity:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream1;
FileOutputStream outputStream2;
String id="dfg";
String key="khdfks";
    outputStream1 = openFileOutput("tt_id",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream2 = openFileOutput("tt_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream1.write(id.getBytes());
outputStream2.write(key.getBytes());
outputStream1.close();
outputStream2.close();
```

I've just started with android app development, so any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't forget to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> permission in your manifest while writing a file to disc

Comment: @KingofMasses but i've written in internal storage

Comment: where ever your saving , you need this permission in manifest to access the saving file

Comment: it works in the first activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify the created file location before read/write. Also make sure the file exists. Else it will throw a file not found exception. To do so try this,

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.txt");
file.createNewFile();
if(file.exists())
{      
    OutputStream outputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(file);     
    String id="dfg";
    outputStream1.write(id.getBytes());
    outputStream1.close();
}
```

Comment: on file.createnewfile i'm getting ioexception while 'new fileoutputstream(file)' is giving filenotfound

Comment: Did you used this permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: but i've written in external storage